# Replace Missing Values with NA in Web Scraping with R

Tags: r, web-scraping, na, rvest, missing-data

I am trying web scraping with R (rvest) for the first time. I am trying to replace missing values with 'NA' but it doesn't seem to work at all. Can  you guys check the code below and please help me?

```
library(rvest)
library('purrr')


link= "https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?title_type=feature&num_votes=25000,&genres=action&sort=user_rating,desc&start=1&ref_=adv_nxt"
page=read_html(link)

movies<-data.frame(name = page %>% html_nodes(".lister-item-header a") %>% html_text,
year = page %>% html_nodes(".text-muted.unbold") %>% html_text(),
certificate = page %>% html_nodes(".certificate") %>% html_text(),
runtime = page %>% html_nodes(".runtime") %>% html_text(),
genre = page %>% html_nodes(".genre") %>% html_text(),
imdb_rating = page %>% html_nodes(".ratings-imdb-rating strong") %>% html_text(),
director = page %>% html_nodes(".text-muted+ p a:nth-child(1)") %>% html_text(),
number_of_votes = page %>% html_nodes(".sort-num_votes-visible span:nth-child(2)") %>% html_text(),
gross = page %>% html_nodes(".ghost~ .text-muted+ span") %>% html_text())
```

The certificate and gross values are missing for certain movies. I tried the following methods to replace missing values with N/A

```
certificate = page %>% 
  html_nodes(".certificate") %>% html_text() %>%  gsub('\\s+', ' ', .)
```

```
gross = page %>% html_nodes(".ghost~ .text-muted+ span") %>% html_text() %>% replace(!nzchar(.),NA)
```

```
certificate = page %>% html_nodes(".certificate") %>% 
  html_text(trim = TRUE) %>%  {if(length(.) == "") NA else .}
```

None of them work for me. The commands execute without error but does not replace the missing values with NA and I get less number of entries.

Without replacing the missing values, I cannot make the movies data frame because I get the error as:

```
error in data.frame(name = page %>% html_nodes(".lister-item-header a") %>%  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 50, 49, 37
```

Comment: Is there some feature (e.g. movie title) common to all the data frames?  If so you could do  a `join()` variant to combine them without needing the same number of rows.

Comment: The task is to extract IMDB top movies. So each column has different values (title, rating, director, ratinng etc). Each columns are scrapped individually with rvest. But when joining all as a data frame, it is giving error because of missing values in certain columns. As far as I know, join() is used to join two data frames with a common variable. But the scenario here is am collating all columns into one data frame, which cannot be achieved if the missing values are replaced with NAs. I hope you got my point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend narrowing your web scraping focus to a specific parent element, such as the cards shown in the image, and then iterating through those elements to extract the specific child elements of interest. This approach will make the process more efficient and targeted. NA will be returned if no element is found in certain cards.

[image]

```
library(tidyverse) 
library(rvest)

movies <-
  "https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?title_type=feature&num_votes=25000,&genres=action&sort=user_rating,desc&start=1&ref_=adv_nxt" %>%
  read_html()

movies %>%
  html_elements(".lister-item-content") %>% # the cards
  map_dfr(~ tibble( # interate through the list and grab the elements:
    title = .x %>% 
      html_element(".lister-item-header a") %>% 
      html_text2(), 
    year = .x %>% 
      html_element(".text-muted.unbold") %>% 
      html_text2(), 
    certificate = .x %>% 
      html_element(".certificate") %>% 
      html_text2(), 
    runtime = .x %>% 
      html_element(".runtime") %>% 
      html_text2(), 
    genre = .x %>% 
      html_element(".genre") %>% 
      html_text2(), 
    rating = .x %>% 
      html_element(".ratings-imdb-rating strong") %>% 
      html_text2(), 
    director = .x %>% 
      html_element(".text-muted+ p a:nth-child(1)") %>% 
      html_text2(), 
    votes = .x %>% 
      html_element(".sort-num_votes-visible span:nth-child(2)") %>%  
      html_text2(), 
    gross = .x %>% 
      html_element(".ghost~ .text-muted+ span") %>% 
      html_text2()
  ))
```

Results

```
# A tibble: 50 × 9
   title                           year  certi…¹ runtime genre rating direc…² votes gross
   <chr>                           <chr> <chr>   <chr>   <chr> <chr>  <chr>   <chr> <chr>
 1 "The Dark Knight"               (200… 15      152 min Acti… 9.0    Christ… 2,66… $534…
 2 "Ringenes herre: Atter en kong… (200… 12      201 min Acti… 9.0    Peter … 1,85… $377…
 3 "Inception"                     (201… 15      148 min Acti… 8.8    Christ… 2,36… $292…
 4 "Ringenes herre: Ringens brors… (200… 12      178 min Acti… 8.8    Peter … 1,88… $315…
 5 "Ringenes herre: To t\u00e5rn"  (200… 12      179 min Acti… 8.8    Peter … 1,67… $342…
 6 "The Matrix"                    (199… 15      136 min Acti… 8.7    Lana W… 1,92… $171…
 7 "Star Wars: Episode V - Imperi… (198… 9       124 min Acti… 8.7    Irvin … 1,29… $290…
 8 "Soorarai Pottru"               (202… NA      153 min Acti… 8.7    Sudha … 117,… NA   
 9 "Stjernekrigen"                 (197… 11      121 min Acti… 8.6    George… 1,37… $322…
10 "Terminator 2 - Dommens dag"    (199… 15      137 min Acti… 8.6    James … 1,10… $204…
# … with 40 more rows, and abbreviated variable names ¹​certificate, ²​director
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Comment: Just a typo from me! Try it now :)

Comment: I am sorry for a noob question, can you please edit your code so that I can loop it and pull all movies from the category "adventure" there are around 1700 movies.  I tried what i have learnt but the result is the first 50 movies pasted multiple times (rbind). @Tom